# relocation of home is not calling .profile at new location

Tags: linux, mount

I relocate my /home/user to another partition with /etc/fstab.

rootfs is on my SSD with the "original" /home/user folder.
I located /home/user to a SD-card.

Why does the system not called the .profile in my new /home/user? Instead it calls the .profile in the SSD/home/user. It seems that the .profile is called before the mount of home/user is done. Why?

This is the entry in my fstab:

/dev/mmcblk1p1 /home vfat defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,uid=user,gid=user,umask=022,user,exec 0 2

So the new mountpoint is also /home I thought this is enough to redirect the home directory

What can I do? Delete the .bashrc, .profile at SSD/home/user?

Thanks

Comment: Did you change your new `home` in `/etc/passwd`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem. There was also a .bash_profile in my home directory. After I deleted it everything works.

Comment: Note that your home directory is the directory listed for your user in `/etc/passwd` (also visible in the output of `getent passwd`). Since you say you are trying to relocate your home directory to some other partition, your answer is unclear when it refers to "my home directory".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).